# Getopt::Long passing several arguments to a subroutine

Tags: perl, getopt-long

How to pass several arguments from command line to a function in `Getopt::Long`? My problem is as follows. I define options in the following way:

```
...

my $result = GetOptions('ham=s{2}' => \&hamming_distance); 

...

sub hamming_distance {
my @values = @_;
...
}
```

If I call the program with option

```
--ham good wood
```

I got two calling of the subroutine `hamming distance`, once with "good" and once with "wood", i.e, the value of `@_` is `ham,good` and then `ham,wood`. How can I get only one call with both parameters - `ham,good,wood`?

Comment: `--ham good wood` doesn't sound like an option, so I wonder sure why it's being implemented as one.

Answer (score 2):

```
my @ham;
my $result = GetOptions('ham=s{2}' => \@ham)
   or usage();

hamming_distance(@ham) if @ham;
```

Comment: That'd work of course, I used another solution - using only one string divided by `,`  `my $result = GetOptions('ham=s' => \&hamming_distance)` and splitting the value inside the `hamming_distance` subroutine. I just thought, there must be some way, how to give the function directly two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a handler subroutine, you could simple create an array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;

my @values;
my $result = GetOptions('ham=s{2}' => \@values); 
print Dumper(\@values);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          'good',
          'wood'
        ];
```

Note that this array method is experimental, according to the documentation.

Comment: It's `{2}` that's experimental, not the use of arrays.